# Android Authentication FAILS in AsyncHttpClient but it's okay with browser

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, android-async-http, loopj

I'm trying to be authenticate from android (Device Samsung GT-i9300 Android 4.3 (API18)) to my platform using the loopj library for AsyncHttppClient. The authentication with browser it's fine, after  user+pass i'll be redirect to my welcome page.

Here is my logcat view:

```
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login I/System.out﹕ Entity content encoding:    null
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login I/System.out﹕ Entity content type: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login I/System.out﹕ Entity content: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@427a66b8
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login I/System.out﹕http://mysite.example.net:8145/
15760-16179/Jac.example.com.my_login D/AsyncHttpClient﹕ Headers were overwritten! (Content-Type | application/json) overwrites (Content-Type | text/plain; charset=ISO-  8859-1)
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 12 from 1 (1200%)
15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login W/JsonHttpResponseHandler﹕ onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized 
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:404 )**
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:161)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:178)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:109)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'll try to explain something:

1. 15760-16179/Jac.example.com.my_login D/AsyncHttpClient﹕ Headers were overwritten! (Content-Type | application/json) overwrites (Content-Type | text/plain; charset=ISO-  8859-1)

I dont understand if it is a good msg or a bad one. I receive this because if I dont set Header manually it gave to me: 
    **W/AsyncHttpClient﹕ Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type**
so i decide to set client.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json"),

2. 15760-15760/Jac.example.com.my_login W/JsonHttpResponseHandler﹕ onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized

I suppose to be something wrong in the Base64.encode so i have try with Base64.DEFAULT and NO_WRAP but nothing has changed.

```
if (user != null && password != null)
{
String orig = user + ":" + password;

//byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(orig.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(orig.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
String credentials = new String(encoded);

// set header 
// HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
// HEADER_APPL_JSON = "application/json";
client.setHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, HEADER_BASIC + " " +credentials);
client.setHeader(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HEADER_APPL_JSON);
}
```

This is mylogin:

```
public static void login(Context context, String user, String password) throws JSONException,   UnsupportedEncodingException {

    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
    jsonParams.put("username", user);
    jsonParams.put("password", password);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());

    if (user != null && password != null){
        String orig = user + ":" + password;
        //byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(orig.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(orig.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String credentials = new String(encoded);

        // set header
        // HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
        // HEADER_APPL_JSON = "application/json";
        client.setHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, HEADER_BASIC + " " +credentials);
        client.setHeader(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HEADER_APPL_JSON);
    }

    client.post(context, "oauth2/auth-token", entity, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        /*
        @Override
        public void onStart(){
            // called before request is started
        }*/

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            try {
                System.out.println("Status code: "+statusCode);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            System.out.println("Status code: "+statusCode);
            System.out.println("Failure - JSONObj");
        }
        /*
        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            // called when request is retried
            System.out.println("Retry No: "+retryNo);
        }*/
    });
}
```

What wrong I am doing? The URL I am using is correct and also the port.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you able to solve this?